# ¿Cuáles son las buenas costumbres al editar posts ajenos?

Tags: discusión, ediciones

Al grano: Yo puse una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/490396/6798). Está incompleta y además, le falta algo que se considera estándar. Soy un usuario activo que suele estar en el sitio y creo que atiendo los comentarios.

Otro usuario con privilegios hace una edición y añade algo que me hacía falta sin siquiera un comentario diciendo "hey, te falta X cosa que es recomendada en este caso". ¿Hay algún tipo de etiqueta o buenas costumbres en estos casos? Dónde está la línea del "estoy respondiendo al editar tu respuesta"?

Es confuso porque estoy de acuerdo con la edición (la respuesta queda mejor y ayuda más a quienes la vayan a usar), pero en qué momento es más sano comentarle respuestas a otros para que editen su propia respuesta y cuándo simplemente vamos a editar una respuesta y ponerle algún estandar de codificación, buena práctica al codificar o cualquier otro ajuste.

Comment: Hasta donde se, las ediciones son permitidas para todos aquellos que hayamos alcanzado el puntaje. Más aún, las ediciones no nos benefician en nada a nosotros, solo a lo que entregamos al sitio y a quienes lo lean. A mi me han incluido ediciones solo de mayúsculas y minúsculas, ni hablar las de solo acentos...

Comment: Me parece que añadir unas comillas no es algo como para mosquearse, es como si se te olvidase poner un punto y coma opcional y alguien te lo pusiera. Ahora, si fuese un cambio grande de código o cambiar el texto escrito para poner otras palabras en tu boca, si que me parecería mal que alguien me hiciese una edición de ese estilo. Para una cosa pequeña como esta no me parece tampoco necesario escribir un comentario, lo único que haría es enredar más el hilo de comentarios de la respuesta y salirse del tema original.

Comment: usar { } es buena practica XD

Comment: En la misma edición aparece el comentario de lo que hizo y porqué. Cuando alguien edita alguna de mis respuestas ahí puedo ver el motivo y, generalmente, es suficiente para darme cuenta de la mejora, por lo que no es necesario comentar. Coincido con @ordago respecto a que eso solo agregaría "ruido" en el desarrollo de pregunta/respuesta.

Comment: Mi experiencia viendo o siguiendo las recomendaciones de los demás, es que simplemente no funciona un, "Hey, pon esto". Sino que es mejor que te hagan la corrección de lo que sea, ya que el que ve tu post es probable que llegue con una mentalidad más fresca a tu publicación.

Comment: De todas maneras, no sé qué tan necesario sea un, "Te puse acentos, comas, separé en párrafos, cambié faltas gramaticales, identé tu código". Porque al final de cuentas es obvio.

Comment: @Cuauhtli necesario o no, es mejora del texto, lo que es permitido como edición.

Comment: @Excorpion Me refiero a que, además de hacer la edición, escribir el motivo de ese tipo de ediciones. ¿Es necesario comentar, "Hey. Te puse acentos, signos de puntuación, etc..."?

Comment: Olvídalo. Ya lo pensé. Creo que si es necesario comentarlo.

Answer (score 12):

> en qué momento es más sano comentarle respuestas a otros para que editen su propia respuesta y cuándo simplemente vamos a editar una respuesta y ponerle algún estandar de codificación, buena práctica al codificar o cualquier otro ajuste.

Yo creo que depende de qué tipo de cambio estamos hablando:

### Cambios al contenido de la respuesta

Si encontrás una respuesta que pensás que debería ser distinta (cambios en el código / otra idea) entonces no podés hacer una edición. En este caso, lo ideal es poner un comentario para discutir los cambios, y que la persona que responde haga los cambios que crea pertinentes. En este caso, puede ser buena idea que hagas tu respuesta :D

En [el caso particular que comentás](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/490396/5) el cambio implica tocar el código (al agregar las comillas), pero es sin dudas una mejora y no cambia el contenido de la respuesta. Si esto fuera en una pregunta, estaría sin dudas mal (porque puede resolver el bug que da origen a la pregunta), pero en una respuesta no tiene ese problema.

### Cambios en la forma / estilo

Si tenés el tiempo / ganas de editar la respuesta, yo diría que lo hagas :) es más rápido y lleva menos esfuerzo colectivo que dejar un mensaje y que la otra persona lo edite.

<sub>esta es mi opinión, no en calidad ni de moderador (que no soy, porque no fui electo para eso) ni de empleado (que trabajo en un área que no tiene nada que ver a SOes)</sub>

Comment: Gracias por compartir tu opinión. El espíritu de la pregunta es realmente aprender yo mismo a ser más proactivo y tener claro el alcance de mis poderes cuando edito una respuesta. Con suerte, le sirve a los demás también.